# Выбрать случайные элементы списка без повторений

Tags: python, массивы, list

```
a = " Mother was cooking the dinner for two hours ".split()  
print([random.choice(a) for j in range(4)])
```

Это выводит случайные слова из которых получается примитивный текст. Я бы хотел, чтобы слова не повторялись. Я думал найти index всех элементов и сравнивать, если index'ы совпали, то слово не вписывать второй раз, но я не знаю как это сделать.

Comment: `random.shuffle`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть функция [sample](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample)

```
import random

a = " Mother was cooking the dinner for two hours ".split()
print(random.sample(a, 4))
```

Answer (score 2):

Вариант с `random.shuffle`

```
random.shuffle(a)
print(a[:4])
```

Comment: Люблю `shuffle`, но с большим списком это очень нерационально будет )